# Improve Red5 RC1 quality in recording

Tags: video, red5, recording

is there any parameters i can change in red5 in order to improve the quality in recording because i do my best as far as the parameters of the camera are concerned, i use these:

```
cam.setMode(1280, 768, 25);
cam.setQuality(0,85);
```

i tried everything and this is the best i can get but the video recorded is still jittery, is there any parameters to change at server side in red5 configuration? or any other way to improve this?I have made a lot of search in the web but nothing..

I would appreciate any suggestions on this!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Those are pretty high quality settings, I would even say nearly HD. I am not sure of the exact bandwidth calculation here but it seems significant and you should make sure that level is available prior to determining your mode and quality properties. If the proper bw is available I would suggest that you set the bw value in cam.setQuality instead of your value of 85. I would also set the keyframe interval like so cam.setKeyFrameInterval(17) for 25fps.

Set quality: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setQuality()

Set keyframe interval: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setKeyFrameInterval()